# Testing using RHinomock

Tags: c#, .net, testing, mocking

I have a class to test which is tricky to test using Rhinomock unlike normal classes bacause its constructor is injected with a dependency which is not a single interface but an array of Interface objects. Please help me set up all stuff to write a test using rhinomock.

```
namespace ClinicalAdvantage.Domain.UserAppSettings
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    public class Agg : IAgg
    {
        private readonly ISource[] sources;

        public Agg(ISource[] sources)
        {
            this.sources = sources;
         }

        public JObject GetAll()
        {
            var obj = new JObject();
            foreach (var source in this.sources)
            {
                var token = source.GetCurr();
                if (token != null)
                {
                    obj.Add(new JProperty(source.Name, token));
                }
            }

            return obj;
        }
}
```

ISource is an interface which has 2 implementations. GetALL() iterates thro each implementated class object and calls the GetCurr method in each of the object and aggregates the result.  I have to stub GetCurr method to return a standard Jtoken. I am unable to create a mock of this class Agg or a stub of ISource.

```
public interface ISource
    {
        string Name { get; }

        bool Enabled { get; }

        JToken GetCurr();


    }
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot mock class with constructor having array parameter using Rhino Mocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855271/cannot-mock-class-with-constructor-having-array-parameter-using-rhino-mocks)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
[TestClass]
public class AggTest
{
    private ISource Isource;
    private Agg agg;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        Isource = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISource>();
        agg = new Agg(new [Isource]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAll()
    {
        Isource.Stub(x => x.GetCurr()).
            Return(new JToken());

        var jObject = agg.GetAll();

        Assert.IsNotNull(jObject);
        // Do your assertion that all JProperty objects are in the jObject
        // I don't know the syntax
    }
}
```